# Textures Stretching when using Micro-displacement

Tags: texturing, displacement

I've been trying to learn a bit more about micro-displacement in Blender, and I've run into a slight problem.

I have two images that are applied to a single plane, one of which I use as a displacement map, and another one that colors the plane. They are pictured below:

[image: Grayscale circuit-like texture]
[image: The same texture, but colored]

As you can see, they both have the same layout, just different shading.

The material for the plane is extremely simple: it consists of the colored texture being put into a Diffuse shader for the surface, and the bump map's texture being multiplied by 100 before being directly linked to the displacement output.

The plane itself simply is a grid with an adaptive subdivision modifier.

The final render, however, has a slight problem. Although the micro-displacement works great, the colored texture doesn't perfectly map onto the displaced mesh. Namely, at some parts, the texture is stretched, leaving an ugly gradient, like below:

[image: A render, with certain parts of the circuit raised. Along the "walls" are gradients.]

Usually, I would solve this by adjusting the UV mapping, but the UV map does not seem to account for the microdisplacement.

Is there a way that I could fix these gradients, and make them colored all gray?

I apologize if I missed something you might need, this is my first time asking a question here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it OK, if all sidewalls generated by the displacement would be colored grey?

Comment: @bstnhnsl Yes, I wouldn't have a problem with that. Though a general solution would be great for future reference, I was just planning on doing that anyways.